# How can I easily mount a Windows share from my Mac?

Tags: macos, networking, file-sharing, osx-tiger

I'm running Tiger.

I know I can go to finder, click network, find the computer, click connect, wait, select the share, and click OK.

Is there any way I can compress those into a single action?  Terminal commands OK, but I'd like it to produce the same result -- i.e. the share appears in finder, I can unmount it by clicking the eject icon, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods are quick and simple.

1. mount via commandline in Terminal.app:

   sudo mount -t smbfs //username@windows.home.example.com/Shared /Volumes/Shared

The /Volumes/Shared directory needs to exist. Change to fit your network.

2. Use Finder. You're probably familiar with this, but for the readers at home :).

   - Select Finder (clicking the desktop works)
   - Command-K will bring up "Connect to Server" dialog.
   - Type in the URI, for the above share: smb://username@windows.home.example.com/Shared, it will automatically mount on /Volumes/Shared.
   - Click the (+) plus button to add to the favorites list.
   - Connect.

Also, the "clock" button next to the plus will show recently connected fileshares.

3. Bonus! Not really a method, but something you should do so this doesn't need to be done every time you boot.

   - Open Account Login Items: System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login Items (or spotlight search for accounts).
   - Click the (+) plus below the main dialog.
   - Navigate to the share you just mounted, under 'Shared'.
   - Click "Add".
   - Uncheck the "Hide" box on the main dialog, unless you want that folder to open every time you log in.

Comment: There's generally only one share I connect to, so "Cmd-K [return]" looks like it will generally do what I need.  Ta.

Comment: I think you can make an alias too, once you've connected...  Opening the alias will reconnect you.

Answer (score 2):

Apple+K, if I recall correctly, will bring up the connect to dialog.  I seem to recall it also keeping track of recently mounted shares, but I only used the Mac for a short time.

Answer (score 1):

First create a share on the Windows computer, or you may already have administrative shares created per drive.

1. Open Finder

   - Open to the Go menu
   - Select Connect to server...
   - Type in the path of your windows share.

Example:

> smb://computerName/c$

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Connect as above and then drag the desired folder on the share to your dock.  Clicking on this folder will mount the share (if you've saved the password) and take you straight to the folder.